# Why should base64_encode fail?

Tags: php, serialization, base64

> #### Description
>
> Encodes the given data with base64.
>
> This encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport through transport layers that are not 8-bit clean, such as mail bodies.
>
> Base64-encoded data takes about 33% more space than the original data.
>
> #### Return Values
>
> The encoded data, as a string or FALSE on failure.

The above [quote](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) taken from PHP.net claims that the function may fail. But for what reason(s)?

Comment: It would be better to quote the contents of that URL here instead of posting the URL in your question. You can quote text using the `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it may return false on failure. An example would be if you try to encode an array like this:

```
if(base64_encode([])){
  echo "Encoded";
} else {
  echo "Not encoded"; //It will execute this
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore.  base64_encode([]) returns an empty string, not false.  The [latest documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) has also been updated to say:

```
**Return Values**
The encoded data, as a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple,

If the argument you try to encode cannot be encoded due to not being the valid data type, `base64_encode()` will fail. I guess it will return `false` if it does.

For example:

```
$array = array('bla');
var_dump($array);
```

Would fail and return false. It will also throw an `E_WARNING` for passing an invalid argument.

Comment: `base64_encode()` takes bytes and has nothing to do w/ character sets.

Comment: AFAIK the data to be `base64_encode()`d isn't limited to any "format". Your example is about data types.